# Ajax working in Chrome, Firefox and not working in IE

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I have problem, because my code working in Chrome, Firefox and not working in IE. Could someone help me?
I have simple jquery code for getting form:

```
$('.get_my_form').live('click', function(){
    $.ajax({
    url: '/get_my_form',
    success: function(html){
        $('#my_form').html(html);}
        });
})
```

simple main html:

```
  <div id="my_form"></div>
```

also simple view:

```
def get_my_form(request):
    form = MyForm
    return render_to_response('get_form.html', {'form': form})
```

and simple get_form.html:

```
<form action="/something/add_something/">
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <input type="submit" value="Add">
</form>
```

For more, when i change jquery code a litte to:

```
 $('.get_my_form').live('click', function(){
        $.ajax({
        url: '/get_my_form',
        success: function(html){
            alert("AAA");
            $('#my_form').html(html);}
            });
    })
```

There is alert in Chrome but no alert in IE.

**Edit**
My dear. Finally the answer was found. User [Xeo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/843718/xeo) helps me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6975631/ie-everlasting-problem-with-selectors). **BEWARE OF SEMICOLONS!** Without semicolons in every right and possible place IE going bad and mad.

Comment: Can you put the html code, rendered in your browser? Especially the .get_my_form element

Comment: Yes, i getting well rendered code in `example.com/get_my_form/`. There is good form, for both, IE and Chrome.

Comment: When you say "not working" what do you mean?  The form doesn't display? You get an error?  Your computer catches fire?  We need more info to help :-)

Comment: Sorry. My problem in concrete is that form doesn't display.

Comment: `<input type="submit" value="Add">` should change to `<input type="submit" value="Add"/>`

Comment: No errors. How can i check if my computer catches fire?

Comment: @Chamika Sandamal it gives no effect but thanks for good wish.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you change the event handler from click to mouseup? What version of jQuery are you using? A few Google searches show issues with the click handler in IE not using the correct button on left button mouse clicks. It was resolved in later versions of jQuery though.

Also, try the following:

```
$('.get_my_form').live('click', function(e) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/get_my_form',
        success: function(html) {
            $('#my_form').html(html);
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
})
```

Comment: jquery.min 1.6.1, `$('.get_my_form').live('mouseup',` working like original code in my three browsers.

Comment: I try with `e.preventDefault();` but nothing happend.

Comment: call `e.preventDefault();` should be placed before other code lines. or else just put `return false;` at end of the code

Comment: Not help what ever i do. IE is still against me :/