# IE everlasting problem with selectors

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-selectors

I think that i have some problems with jquery selectors in IE. Chrome and Firefox is ok, but not IE. Not only selector from example below not works. Every selectors not works in IE.
I am using jquery 1.6.2 and jquery-ui.min 1.8
Example:
html:

```
<p id="clickme">clik me</p>
```

jquery:

```
$(function(){
       $('#clickme').click(function(){alert('hello')})
})
```

Comment: Do you have multiple elements with the ID clickme in your document? Where are you running the jQuery?

Comment: The chances are the DOM isn't ready to be manipulated. Wrap your code in a `$(document).ready` function and see if that helps.

Comment: @Pekka i have only one clickme id, for sure. I am running jquery when `$(document).ready`

Comment: @James Allardice when i change `$(function(){}` to `$(document).ready()` nothing changed.

Comment: The code you have posted works in all the browsers you mentioned as well as IE. http://jsfiddle.net/zSKRQ/. Could you please post the rest of your code. Could you maybe create a http://jsfiddle.net if it is too much to put in here.

Comment: I won't show all my html code because there is more things about my project and i don't want it to be public. Sorry. But i can say that all things don't work in IE. Just like there is no js.

Comment: Sorry i can't show all code. Sorry for wasting Your time. Let forget about the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I have had tons of problems with syntax on IE. Get in the habit of using semi colons. I looked at your JavaScript file and there was quite a few that seem to be non existent.

```
$('#clickme').click(function(){
    alert('hello');
});
```

Comment: Amazing. Your code working. It is because of i don't have semi colons. Uff.. I feel free.. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I ran into a few different IE parsing errors, this one I never forgot! You're welcome

Comment: If You have any more tips of for what i should especially beware i will willingly listen.

Comment: Just be in the habit of always writing in lines and staggering. It helps connect the dots and find syntax errors.

Answer (score 1):

you should insert your code in document ready function of your js first.you should insert simicolon at the end of click function too.

for better help ,please insert your code completly here.

Comment: Semicolon is not an issue, but document ready is the correct answer indeed.

Comment: My code has 110 lines and not works only in IE. Should i put all my code here?

Comment: @Shadow Wizard - I assumed document ready would be the correct answer, but apparently it's not. See comments on question.

Comment: you can upload your page in a host and link it here.

Comment: dear cris please insert your codes completly to better understanding!

Comment: no problem.just,you can  write a simple alert in first of your code and then check it while the alert dosn't work.with this way you can debug your js and find the correct position of your problem.

Comment: I was debuging as You say, but nothing happends to the time when i start using fully semi coloned code.